# How can I save fragment state when the user navigates between fragments in a viewpager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm making an Android App, that uses BottomNavigationViewEx to have a Bottom Navigation widget with 5 sections/fragments, I manage them using a viewpager, but one of this fragment (fragment #3) also uses a tab layout to nest another 2 fragments and I need to keep the selected tab when the user navigates to other fragment using the BottomNavigation icons.

The problem is that I need save the state of the fragment #3 (juts to keep it simple, I call them in this post fragment #), that is the fragment that holds the tablayout.

Inside fragment #3 I'm calling:

```
   override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)


    outState.putInt("currentDirectoryFragmentId",tabLayout!!.selectedTabPosition)
}
```

but the method is never being called, and makes sense, because I really never destroy the parent activity, but `onDestroy()` is being called inside each fragment correctly.

So, How can I save the state of a fragment when the user navigates between fragments that are children of a same activity?

Comment: You could overwrite onPause() to save the fragment and selected tab, and onResume() to put it back to what it was priviously

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments. You can accomplish this by using a variable inside the parent activity and referring to and setting this variable inside the fragments' `onPause()` & `onResume()` methods.

**Inside Parent Activity**

```
public static int position = -1;
```

**Inside Child Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MainActivity.position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(MainActivity.position);
    super.onResume();
}
```